# how to use "mount /system" in Android Recovery Mode?

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode

How can I mount /system in Android Recovery Mode on my Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime?

Any article or tutorial on it would be helpful.

I spent like 5 hours reading every forum post on how to do it.

I'm going to make the bold claim that I don't think ANYBODY on the internet has used this feature. Happy to have anyone prove me wrong.

EDIT: what am I trying to do: I'm trying to enable USB debugging by modifying /system/build.prop, then I can normal-boot my Android and use a remote-control software like Vysor to recover data.

[image]

Comment: What are you really trying to do by mounting system image? It is not like you would get adb shell on this recovery, and the GUI does not seem to allow running arbitrary commands. What's the point in mounting system image then? Use a custom recovery such as TWRP.

Comment: If your phone is already bootloader unlocked you can install TWRP for your phone: https://twrp.me/samsung/samsunggalaxygrandprime.html BTW: The title is usually used to summarize your question, a reader should be able to understand your question even without the title.

Comment: just forget about this option, it's a leftover and pointless on production builds

Comment: what am I trying to do: I'm trying to enable USB debugging by modifying /system/build.prop, then I can normal-boot my Android and use a remote-control software like Vysor to recover data.